# How can I loop over rows in my DataFrame, calculate a value and put that value in a new column with this lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, python-3.6

`./test.csv` looks like:

```
     price     datetime
1    100       2019-10-10
2    150       2019-11-10
...

import pandas as pd    
import datetime as date
import datetime as time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

csv_df = pd.read_csv('./test.csv')

today = datetime.today()

csv_df['datetime'] = csv_df['expiration_date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x)) #convert `expiration_date` to datetime Series


def days_until_exp(expiration_date, today):


    diff = (expiration_date - today)
    return [diff]

csv_df['days_until_expiration'] = csv_df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: days_until_exp(csv_df['datetime'], today))
```

I am trying to iterate over a specific column in my DateFrame labeled `csv_df['datetime']` which in each cell has just one value, a date, and do a calcation defined by `diff`.

Then I want the single value `diff` to be put into the new Series `csv_df['days_until_expiration']`.

The problem is, it's calculating values for every row (673 rows) and putting all those values in a list in each row of `csv_df['days_until_expiration`. I realize it may be due to the brackets around `[diff]`, but without them I get an error.

In Excel, I would just do something like =SUM(datetime - price) and click and drag down the rows to have it populate a new column. However, I want to do this in Pandas as it's part of a bigger application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csv_df['datetime']` is series, so `x` of `apply` is each cell of series. You call `apply` with `lambda` and `days_until_exp()`, but you doesn't passing `x` to it. Therefore, the result is wrong.

Anyway, Without your sample data, I guess that you want to find `sum` of `csv_df['datetime']` - today(). To do this, you don't need `apply`. Just do direct vectorized operation on series and `sum`.

I make 2 columns dataframe for sample:

```
csv_df:
    datetime  days_until_expiration
0 2019-09-01                    NaN
1 2019-09-02                    NaN
2 2019-09-03                    NaN
```

Do the following return series of delta between `csv_df['datetime']` and `today()`. I guess you want this::

```
td = datetime.datetime.today()    
csv_df['days_until_expiration'] = (csv_df['datetime'] - td).dt.days

csv_df:
    datetime  days_until_expiration
0 2019-09-01                    115
1 2019-09-02                    116
2 2019-09-03                    117
```

---

OR:
To find `sum` of all deltas and assign the same `sum` value to `csv_df['days_until_expiration']`

```
csv_df['days_until_expiration'] = (csv_df['datetime'] - td).dt.days.sum()

csv_df:
    datetime  days_until_expiration
0 2019-09-01                    348
1 2019-09-02                    348
2 2019-09-03                    348
```